# "Symbols not found" linker error after making string array constexpr

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, c-preprocessor, constexpr

I'm toying with a method of converting an enum to a string using the preprocessor. It was building just fine until I decided to try to make the class members static. In order to do this, I use `constexpr` to build the array of strings. However after this change, I get a linker error saying:

> "HeadphoneTypesUtils::HeadphoneTypesStringArray" symbols not found,

and can't figure out why. XCode 5.1 by the way.

**Contents of the Headphones.def file**

```
X(  HeadphoneTypesGenericBuds  )
X(  HeadphoneTypesGenericCircumaural  )
X(  HeadphoneTypesUnknown  )
```

**Contents of HeadphoneTypes.h**

```
/// This is a C-style enum for my Obj-C chums
typedef enum  {
#   define X(a) a,
#   include "Headphones.def"
#   undef X
    HeadphoneTypesCount
} HeadphoneTypes;
```

**Class implementation**

```
#include "HeadphoneTypes.h"
class HeadphoneTypesUtils
{
    static constexpr char const* const HeadphoneTypesStringArray[] = {
#   define X(a) #a,
#   include "Headphones.def"
#   undef X
        0
    };

public:
    static std::string toString( HeadphoneTypes t ) 
    {
        if (t >= HeadphoneTypesCount || t < 0) return toString(HeadphoneTypesUnknown);
        return HeadphoneTypesStringArray[t];
    }
};
```

Comment: Looks like an Xcode bug; clang and gcc are happy.  Maybe make it a function local static?

Comment: Yeah, the static local function works fine, as does making the class into a namespace instead. Grrr @ XCode!